# Optimizing and improving a username regex

Tags: c#, optimization, regex

I have created this regular expression to validate usernames which I need in my projects:

```
^(?=.{3,32}$)(?!.*[._-]{2})(?!.*[0-9]{5,})[a-z](?:[\w]*|[a-z\d\.]*|[a-z\d-]*)[a-z0-9]$
```

It works just fine. But I'm wondering if there is any improvement and optimization for it, since I'm not exactly a regex-guy.

The regex and tests are available [here](http://rubular.com/r/r0HTd3Oy2t).

Rules are:

- usernames should start with `[a-z]`
- usernames should end with `[a-z0-9]`
- usernames can have a length between 3 and 32
- usernames can contain any of `[a-z0-9\._-]`
- Numbers should not be in the vicinity of each other more than 4 times. I mean `p1234` is a match and `p12345` is not.
- each username can contains only one of `[\._-]`. I mean a username can contain `.` or `-` or `_`
- each `.`, `-`, and `_` should be followed by an alpha-numeric. I mean a `.` can not be followed by another `.`. They should not be in the vicinity of each other.

Tests:

```
j1vad-amiry            match
j1vad-ami-ry           match
ja23d_am8ry            match
ja_23d_am8ry           match
jav5d2.am3y            match
jav.ad.amiry           match
jav.ad.ami.ry.2        match
ja3fd4                 match
page2491               match
page24915              not match
jav-ad_amiry           not match
javad_am-iry           not match
jav.ami-ry             not match
jav.ami_ry             not match
jav.ami__ry            not match
2jav                   not match
2jav_ad                not match
2jav_ad3               not match
```

Comment: Do you *have* to solve this problem with a regex only? Although it might be possible to solve this with a regex, it seems like a lot of work and the result is pretty much unreadable. Can you write some code in C# to check those rules instead?

Comment: @GregHewgill Well, using regex give me an option to check usernames in both server and client side with minimum coding.

Comment: Maybe, but you would have to validate your solution carefully on both sides because not all regex languages are created alike.

Comment: Your last edit invalidated part of an answer. I have rolled it back. [Please see this meta post about why we frown on editing code in questions.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/41243)

Comment: Would just like to say that *Regex* (or *username* in the title) are not pieces of code and shouldn't be stylicized as such.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would very strongly recommend against using a regular expression for this. There is no clear mapping between the list of requirements you posted and the code.

Imagine another developer looking at this. Are they able to deduce the list of requirements? Given the list of requirements, are they able to verify that the regular expression is correct? How long would it take to convince them that it's correct?

In fact, it's not correct. The character class `\d` [is not the same](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DigitCharacter) as `[0-9]` (unless you specify ECMAScript-compliant behaviour), and your regexp matches the username `j1vad-a٠miry` (that's an `ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO`). (It doesn't match on the link you posted, but that's a Ruby, not .NET, regexp tester.)

Now suppose one of your requirements changes -- this code is going to be tricky to maintain.

Instead, I would recommend writing a series of tests, each corresponding to one of your requirements. Here is the code I came up with. It still uses regular expressions where appropriate, but very simple ones.

```
public static bool IsValidUsername(string username)
{
    if (username == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var length = username.Length;
    if (length < 3 || length > 32)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!IsLowerAlpha(username[0]))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!IsLowerAlphanumeric(username[length - 1]))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!Regex.IsMatch(username, "^[a-z0-9._-]*$"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (Regex.IsMatch(username, "[0-9]{5,}"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Each username can contain only one of '.', '_', '-'.
    var punctuation = new [] { '.', '_', '-' };
    if (punctuation.Count(c => username.Contains(c)) > 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Each '.', '_', and '-' should be followed by an alpha-numeric.
    for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (punctuation.Contains(username[i]) && !IsLowerAlphanumeric(username[i + 1]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static bool IsLowerAlpha(char c)
{
    return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
}

private static bool IsLowerAlphanumeric(char c)
{
    return IsLowerAlpha(c) || (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}
```

Now, `IsValidUsername` is getting a bit long. We could split out each check into a separate static method, for instance,

```
private static bool IsNotNull(string username)
{
    return username != null;
}

private static bool IsInLengthRange(string username)
{
    var length = username.Length;
    return length >= 3 && length <= 32;
}
```

And then just check our rules like this:

```
private static readonly Predicate<string>[] Rules = new Predicate<string>[]
{
    IsNotNull,
    IsInLengthRange,
    StartsWithLowerAlpha,
    ...
};

public static bool IsValidUsername(string username)
{
    return Rules.All(rule => rule(username));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using lookarounds is going to force your regular expression to execute slowly. They will cause the matching engine to start iterating over the string only to restart once the assertion passes.

You should take a step back and think about how much is being put into this single expression. Checking the length of a string is trivial in any programming language. In many languages, it is O(1) since the length is stored with the character values. Having to explicitly write this check for client and server code does not require extensive extra coding.

Taking another step back. Do you really need to be this restrictive with the user name? If the only valid characters are `[a-z0-9\._-]`, you aren't bumping up against escaping requirements. It took me a few tries to fully understand the rules you had spelled out. You shouldn't require your user to work that hard just to come up with a user name.

Use `0-9` or `\d`, not both. Consistency is always important.

Comment: Good point about `[0-9]` and `\d` -- it jogged my memory that they're not actually the same.

Comment: @mjolka: The joys of regex being far from standard across languages.